# Integrating $\frac{1}{(x^2+b)^{3/2}}$?

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

How to integrate $$\int\frac{1}{(x^2+b)^{3/2}}dx$$ using the hyperbolic sine substitution ?

Comment: Why impose this odd requirement?

Comment: Do you have a better idea in mind ?

Comment: Looks like you got answers...

Comment: It would also help those answering if you were to offer some of your thoughts and how far you were able to proceed with the problem before asking your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Take $x = \sqrt b \sinh t $ then $dx = \sqrt b \cosh t\, dt$ and

$$\int \frac{\sqrt b \cosh t }{(b \cosh^2 t)^{3/2}} \, dt = \int \frac{1}{b \cosh^2 t} \, dt = \color {#f05}{\frac{\tanh t}{b} + C} $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Put $x=\sqrt b \sinh t$ for $b>0$ so the integral becomes 
$$
\int \frac{1}{b^{3/2}\cosh^3 t}\sqrt b \cosh t \,\mathrm{d}t=....
$$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: if $b = 0$, it is a trivial case...
if $b > 0$, let $u = \sqrt{b}\cdot \tan x$.
if $b < 0$, let $u = \sqrt{b} \cdot \sec x$. Can you continue?